# Installing a local NPM package from its folder ignores the package's "files" configuration

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, node-modules, npm-install

TL;DR Packaging my local npm package works fine and it ignore the non-distribution file, but installing it from it's folder includes all files.

Environment:

- Node: v14
- NPM: v7
- Babel: V7

I have a small reusable component library (`./common/components`) I want to share between my apps. I'm using Babel to build its `src` code into a `lib` folder - which seems to work fine. When I run a `npm pack` command, I can see that only the `lib` folder and the `package.json` files get included in the package TGZ file. But when I install the package in one of my apps with `npm i ../../common/components`, then all the package's code (`src`, `node_modules`, `.babelrc.json`, `package-lock.json`, etc.) gets included in the app's `node_modules` folder.

What am I doing wrong, or am I misunderstanding something? Is there a way for me to install only the `lib` folder?

Here is my component package's code:

- `package.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "name": "components",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "lib/*",
    "files": [
      "lib/*"
    ],
    "scripts": {
      "clean": "rimraf ./lib",
      "postinstall": "npm run build",
      "prebuild": "npm run clean",
      "build": "babel src --out-dir lib --copy-files"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/cli": "7.14.5",
      "@babel/core": "7.14.6",
      "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.7",
      "rimraf": "3.0.2"
    }
  }
  ```
- `.babelrc.json`:

  ```json
  {
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  }
  ```
- Here's my output from `npm pack`:

  [image]

Here's my app's code:

- `package.json`:

  ```json
  {
    ...
    "dependencies": {
      "components": "file:../../common/components",
      ...
    },
    ...
  }
  ```
- Here's what gets installed to the app's `node_modules` folder:

  [image]

Comment: FWIW I have the same issue - local install copies everything, ignoring the `files` section. NPM v8.3.1. `npm pack` and installing from the tgz works fine.